# I can't add a background image to grub : permission denied

Tags: grub2, permissions, sudo, gedit, desktop-background

I'm trying to add a BACKGROUND_IMAGE to GRUB, so I edited grub-mkconfig using gedit. After saving, I updated it, result is below:

```
sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for harish: 
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 13: /etc/default/grub: /home/harish/Pictures  /grubbackground.png: Permission denied
```

Why is that? thought I added `sudo` for root permissions.

Note: I have two separate partitions for `/` and `/home`

EDIT: I followed instructions said by [doru](https://askubuntu.com/users/445261/doru) but that is giving same error. See picture below:

[image]

Comment: Exactly how did you edit `grub-mkconfig` file? It's not the file to be edited. Also let us know if there is any `GRUB_BACKGROUND` line in `/etc/default/grub` file

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Grub2/Displays - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Displays)

The user has two options for selecting the splash image to be used.

1. The first requires editing a GRUB2 configuration file.

   - Open `/etc/default/grub` with a text editor:

     ```
      gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
     ```
   - Add the following line:

     ```
      GRUB_BACKGROUND="/home/harish/Pictures/grubbackground.png"
     ```
2. The second is to copy a compatible image file to the grub folder.

   - Run nautilus with root permissions to copy and paste a suitable image in the grub folder (*The default location for this folder is /boot/grub*):

     gksu nautilus /home/harish/Pictures/
   - Right click and select copy on *grubbackground.png*
   - While on the same window, navigate to `/boot/grub/` and paste the image.
   - Right click the image and check that the permissions are as shown below:

[image: Sample Image of Speedofme]

- You may now <kbd>Close</kbd> this window.

*If more than one suitable image resides in the grub folder, the priority for the image used in GRUB2 is: First image found in /boot/grub.*

- The first image found, in this order: jpg, JPG, jpeg, JPEG, png, PNG, tga, TGA
- If multiple images of the same extension, alphanumerically.

After choosing your prefered method:

- Update GRUB to incorporate the image into the GRUB2 menu:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```

Keep in mind that if you applied both methods,
GRUB2 will prefer the configuration file (option 1).

Answer (score 1):

To change the GRUB background image you only have to put your new image in the `/boot/grub/` folder and then to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and that should do it. See [this article](http://www.ostechnix.com/configure-grub-2-boot-loader-settings-ubuntu-16-04/) for more info.

Comment: yup! but failed to COPY image to there.. the paste option has disabled

Comment: Have you tried to run in the folder with the image `sudo cp image.png /boot/grub/` with the image name instead `image.png`?

Comment: not yet. i just had tried to copy by dragging from another folder to THIS folder.

Comment: @harishmukkara did it work?

Comment: same error . see the image tagged to the question

Comment: @harishmukkara you shouldn't have edited `grub-mkconfig`. Undo the changes and then use this method and it should work. For me it worked flawlessly.

Comment: @harishmukkara you really should undo your changes to `grub-mkconfig`. @doru your method doesn't work because you need to be root to copy and paste the image to `/boot/grub/`. Check my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to change the grub background image is to edit `/etc/default/grub` as root and add

`GRUB_BACKGROUND="/the_exact_path_to_the_image"`

right below the line that reads: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`.

Save the file and run `sudo update-grub` to activate it.  **DO NOT** forget to enclose the path in double quotes and make sure your image is readable by **others** on its permissions.

If you decide to use this method, you must delete the image you copied in `/boot/grub` manually before you `update-grub`.